# Can't SSH between two servers

Tags: server, ssh, rsync, vps

I recently purchased a new VPS to replace my old VPS and was in the process of using `rsync` to copy files over.

Part way through `rsync` hung up and now it won't make a connection again it just times out.

I can't `rsync` over `ssh` or `ssh` directly to the other server now. When I ping it doesn't get a response so it just sits with the first line

```
PING -- 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and never goes past that.

If I go over to the destination server and try to `ssh` back into the other one I get

`ssh: connect to host -- port 22: No route to host`

I also get `Destination Host Unreachable` if I try to ping.

I am `ssh`ing into both of them successfully using putty from my home PC and I can `ssh` out of both of them successfully to another third party.

I have no idea what's going on other than possibly one of the providers blacklisted the other during the `rsync`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check /etc/hosts.deny to make sure nothing has actually been blacklisted directly here. Otherwise, if iptables is installed, check it hasn't blacklisted something with `iptables -L INPUT -v -n`. You can try whitelisting the relevant IP too ([see this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables)).

Considering you can SSH into them from home or from other servers, if you can't solve this, your best bet would be to use a third party (either your computer or one of those other servers) as an intermediary. rsync from your old server to your third server, then from your third server to your new server. Possibly you can also use SSH port-forwarding if you don't want to leave any data in the middle, though it will still pass through that third server.

Comment: iptables are all clear, nothing out of the ordinary in the hosts.deny files either. I have already FTP'd most of the files I need of the old server, I'm redoing most things so I don't need 90% of the stuff on the server. At this point I'm just trying to figure out what caused it and how to avoid it or fix it.

Comment: Have you tried `nmap`ing from one side or the other? Since it won't respond to ping you'll have to use the `-Pn` option, but it should give you an idea of if everything is really blocked.

Comment: Alright, just ran nmap. Not sure if it gives any more useful info.

**From Old To New**

`root@*:~# nmap -Pn *.*.*.*

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-18 08:28 MSK
Nmap scan report for *-*-*-*-host.colocrossing.com (*.*.*.*)
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on *-*-*-*-host.colocrossing.com (*.*.*.*) are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.57 seconds`

Comment: **From New To Old**

`root@:~# nmap -Pn *.*.*.*

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-18 01:25 EDT
Nmap scan report for host.colocrossing.com (*.*.*.*)
Host is up (0.000020s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on host.colocrossing.com (*.*.*.*) are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.19 seconds`

Comment: Hm, there really is no connection. I must admit I'm getting more and more stumped. DNS resolution seems fine, at least. The only thing I can think of now is to try using `traceroute` to determine where the connection fails. That will at least allow you to see if the issue comes from the server(s) or from somewhere in between. You might have to play with the options to get a better output.

Comment: I tried trace routes originally. New to old won't make one hop, old to new seems to go somewhere, just not all the way. Makes me think maybe the new provider has filtered any outgoing traffic to that IP

Comment: I think at this point if you want to figure it out you'll have to ask support directly, see if they can tell you if they blacklisted something. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.